# Declaring 2000 functions in R for use with genetic algorithm

Tags: r

I'm setting the constraints for my genetic algorithm(GA) implementation. My fitness function is comprised of many functions.

I'm currently doing this:

```
c1 <- function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[1, ] %*% x - work_hrs[1])
c2 <- function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[2, ] %*% x - work_hrs[2])
c3 <- function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[3, ] %*% x - work_hrs[3])
c4 <- function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[4, ] %*% x - work_hrs[4])
c5 <- function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[5, ] %*% x - work_hrs[5])
.
.
.
c2000 <- function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[2000, ] %*% x - work_hrs[2000])
```

x is a 12x1 matrix, case_cnts a 2000x12 matrices, and work_hrs a 2000x1 matrix but that's not really important for my question.

Typing out the 2000 lines it takes to declare c1 - c2000 does not take long with the use of Excel and the "concatenate" function but it makes for very long code. How can I do this with a loop?

I tried:

```
for (g in 1:2000)
 {
 paste0("c",g) = function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[g,] %*% x - work_hrs[g])
 }
```

and got this error:

```
Error in paste0("c", g) = function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[g, ] %*% x  
-  : target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I will also need to do the same with the line of code below

```
if (abs(c1(x)) >= 10000 ) {penalty1 = 1000} else if (abs(c1(x)) >= 1000 & abs(c1(x)) < 10000) {penalty1 = 100} else if (abs(c1(x)) >= 100 & abs(c1(x)) < 1000) {penalty1 = 10} else if (abs(c1(x)) > 0 & abs(c1(x)) < 100 ) {penalty1 = 2}
```

Comment: why not just do something like `function(row, x, num) {as.numeric(case_cnts[row,] %*% x - work_hrs[num])`?

Comment: Dylan, this is not what I'm looking for. I need something along the lines of what Akrun suggested.

Comment: So you actually need 2000 functions declared in your environment? I've never seen that before since it looks like you can just generalize it to what I put. The only difference between my answer and akrun's is that he assigns it to your environment.

Comment: Yeah, need functions in environment. All of these dynamic variables will be needed to build a "cost" function.

Comment: I really doubt you actually need that. I really think that your project is weakly designed and that @dykanjm is right.

Comment: @mbs1 I think you need `for(i in 1:2000) assign(paste0("c", i), eval(parse(text = paste0("function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[", i, ",] %*% x - work_hrs[", i, "])"))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `assign`

```
for(i in 1:2000){
   assign(paste0("c", i), eval(parse(text = paste0("function(x) 
        as.numeric(case_cnts[", i, ",] %*% x - work_hrs[", i, "])"))))

    }

c1
#function(x) as.numeric(case_cnts[1,] %*% x - work_hrs[1])
```

Comment: I need there to be a number where the 'i' is akrun. Using this, all of the functions return the same output.

Comment: This is twice incorrect. First if you need to assign in a loop you are 100% sure to do something wrong. And even so, this code does not do what you think it does. `i` evaluated at runtime an thus is 2000 for each function.

Comment: No direct way. You can find a workaround with functional programming but well... you should rethink your code.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are asking but as mentioned @dylanjm you are likely doing something wrong. According to your question what you are trying to do looks like

```
penalties <- numeric(2000)

for (i in 1:2000)
{
  y <- as.numeric(case_cnts[i,] %*% x - work_hrs[i])

  if (abs(y) >= 10000) 
    penalties[i] = 1000
  else if (abs(y) >= 1000 & abs(y) < 10000) 
    penalties[i] = 100
  else if (abs(y) >= 100 & abs(y) < 1000) 
    penalties[i] = 10
  else if (abs(y) > 0 & abs(y) < 100 ) 
    penalties[i] = 2
}
```